# How to duplicate form div elements?

Tags: javascript

This code is not working when I am trying to duplicate form elements or DIV.But the code is working when removing form tag.I want to be able to duplicate Div under form Tag using plain javascript.

```
function display(){
    var a = document.getElementsById('clone');
    var b = document.getElementsByID('group');
    var c = b.cloneNode(true);
    a.appendChild(c);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have mistyped `document.getElementsByID('group')`. The function name should be [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Also for future, you can use [the developer console](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp) console to see if there is something wrong.

Comment: Also not that the function name ends with a small *d*. In the question the second one ends with *D*. So `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`. **EDIT:** I see you  mentioned it in your edit, nevermind then. :)